# How can mapStateToProps receive the updated state in react-redux implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm learning react and redux implementation, and encountered a bug I cannot find a fix for.
The function `mapStateToProps` gets the initial (and empty) state.
I'm using seamless-Immutable for the state object, and I know that my reducer is in fact being called and updates the state.
I have tried every component-props related methods (`componentWillReceiveProps` , `componentWillMount` , `componentDidMount` , etc..), and
`mapStateToProps` never receives the **updated** state; always initial empty state. it runs before `this.props.dispatch` can be called within those methods.

I must be missing something...

**relevant files:**

**1. app/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './index.css';
import PlaylistList from '../../components/PlaylistList';
import { fetchPlaylists } from '../../store/playlists/actions';
import { getPlaylists } from '../../store/playlists/reducer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaylists();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to My Music Store</h2>
        </div>
        <PlaylistList playlists={this.props.playlists}></PlaylistList>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.dir(state); // prints the initial state (before reducer run)
  return {playlists: getPlaylists(state)}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**2. actions.js:**

```
import * as api from '../../services/api';
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import _keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy';

export function fetchPlaylists() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try{
      const playlists = await api.fetchPlaylists();
      const playlistsById = _keyBy(playlists, (playlist) => playlist.id);
      dispatch( {  type: types.PLAYLISTS_FETCHED, playlistsById} );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

**3. reducer.js:**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import _mapKeys from 'lodash/mapKeys';
import _mapValues from 'lodash/mapValues';
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';

const initialState = Immutable({
    playlistsById: {},
    currentPlaylist: undefined
  }
);

export default function reduce(state = initialState, action = {}){
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.PLAYLISTS_FETCHED:
      return state.merge({
        playlistsById: action.playlistsById
      })
    default: return state

  }
}

export function getPlaylists(state) {
  let playlistsById = state.playlistsById;
  let playlistIds = _mapKeys(state.playlistsById);
  console.dir({playlistsById, playlistIds}); // prints empty objects
}
```

**4. reducers.js:**

```
import playlistsReducer from './playlists/reducer';

export { playlistsReducer };
```

**5. actionTypes.js**

```
export const PLAYLISTS_FETCHED = 'playlists.PLAYLISTS_FETCHED';
export const PLAYLIST_ADDED = 'playlists.PLAYLIST_ADDED';
export const PLAYLIST_REMOVED = 'playlists.PLAYLIST_REMOVED';
export const PLAYLIST_UPDATED = 'playlists.PLAYLIST_UPDATED';
export const FILTER_BY_SEARCH = 'playlists.FILTER_BY_SEARCH';
```

**6. src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './containers/App';
import './index.css';
import * as reducers from './store/reducers';

const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers), applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is that in `mapStateToProps` you expect the `state` argument to refer a state of your `playlistsReducer`, while in fact it refers to an entire state object with all your reducers combined by `combineReducers` function.

The correct path to the `playlistsReducer` in the state would be - `state.playlistsReducer`. As a result, your `mapStateToProps` has to look like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.dir(state.playlistsReducer); // prints the initial state (before reducer run)
  return {playlists: getPlaylists(state.playlistsReducer)}
}
```

By using this `mapStateToProps`, `getPlaylists` will receive a correct object with needed data to pass required props to the component.

Another major issue is that `getPlaylists` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: well, I changed it to `state.playlistsReducer` but no good. still contains no data...

Comment: If you're saying that the state is updated when the action is dispatched and mapStateToProps isn't called after it, that it seems very strange. Could you put this code in some developer playground, like codepen.io, so I can play around with it?

Comment: So, I've tested your code and noticed following issues: 1) You should check if `this.props.playlists` is not `undefined` in render method of your component, otherwise you'll be getting an exception. 2) Instead of `componentWillReceiveProps` you need to use `componentDidMount`, as former isn't called during an initial load. 3) `getPlaylists` function doesn't return anything. After fixing these issues, you'll notice that you `map` function in component's render method isn't suitable for type of data you receive in the prop.